# Python Selenium click button that belongs in a specific class

Tags: python, selenium

In my webpage i have multiple "block_container" and  multiple "market marketGroup". I also have multiple Over 2,5. I want to click the Over 0,5 that corresponds to the "block_container" or the "market marketGroup" that contains "Αγορές Γκολ Αγώνα".

form_element=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Over 2,5') ]")

This will find the locations of all Over 2.5. I need only the Over 2.5 button that corresponds to the div/class that "Αγορές Γκολ Αγώνα" lives in.

```
<div class="block_container">
        <div class="market marketGroup">
            <div class="title">
                <div class="favorites_star" data-bind="click : $parents[3].FavoriteMarketsModule.ToggleFavoriteItem , css: { starred: $parents[3].FavoriteMarketsModule.IsInFavorites($data) }, attr: { 'ga-action' : $data.Sysname() }" ga-category="Live Bet Favorites" ga-action="SOCCER_GOAL_LINES">
                    <span class="icon-star"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- ko text:  $data.Caption -->Αγορές Γκολ Αγώνα<!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <!-- ko foreach: BetViews -->
            <!-- ko template: { name: Template } -->
    <div class="bet_row double">
        <!-- ko foreach: BetItems -->
        <!-- ko template: { name: 'tmpl_betitem' } -->
    <!-- ko ifnot: $data==null -->
    <div class="bet oddItem live" data-bind="attr: { 'data-betid': CompositeId, 'data-betprice': Price }, css:{ locked: !IsAvailable(), selected: IsSelected }, TooltipText:{value:$data.Caption()}" data-betid="e12711451-906298140" data-betprice="1.18" title="" data-original-title="Over 2,5">
        <span class="oddItem_caption" data-bind="TooltipText:{value: $data.Caption(), delay:200,container:'body'}" title="" data-original-title="Over 2,5"><!-- ko text: $data.Caption -->Over 2,5<!-- /ko --></span>
        <span class="oddItem_value" data-bind="text: $data.OddsText">1.18</span>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: $data==null --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following xpath:

```
xpath = "//div[contains(text(),'Αγορές Γκολ Αγώνα')]/../span[contains(text(),'Over 2,5')]"
```

Comment: Share the URL you are trying